# Embedding multiline alert box in php code

Tags: javascript, php, multiline

I would like to embed a JavaScript alert box into php code and would like the text to report variable values.  The following code gives multiline but does not enable me to use variables.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Total size of all files too large.\nConsider uploading files in smaller sets.\nYou can append to existing sets.");
document.location.href="SomewhereElse.php";
</script>
<?php
```

The following code lets me use variables but does not give multiline.

```
$Str="Total size cannot be not more than " . ini_get('post_max_size');
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo "alert('" . $Str . "');";
echo "</script>";
```

When I try this code, no alert box comes up.

```
    $Str="Unable to load (all of) these files because of their (total) size" .
    "\nPlease make the upload set conform to the following parameters";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('" . $Str . "');";
    echo "</script>";
```

I do get an alert box if I leave the \n (before the Please) out but it is not multiline.  I am wondering if the \n dismisses the alert box.  At any rate, how do I get a multiline alert box with variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<?php

 $max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
 echo '<script>';
 echo 'alert("Total size cannot be more than ' . $max_size . '!\nPlease make sure...");';
 echo '</script>';

?>
```